# Resume prevented form submission in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments, form-submit

I'm implementing Stripe with React.

Upon submit click, the form submission is prevented and an ajax request goes to Stripe - giving us a token in the response which should be attached in the subsequent request to our server.

**I'm stumbling on how to implement/trigger this subsequent request to our server?**

Below is an example of this flow taken from the [react-stripe-elements](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements/blob/master/demo/index.js) repository:

```
class _CardForm extends React.Component {
  props: {
    fontSize: string,
    stripe: StripeProps,
  }
  handleSubmit = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    this.props.stripe.createToken().then((payload) => console.log(payload));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Card details
          <CardElement
            onChange={handleChange}
            onFocus={handleFocus}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            onReady={handleReady}
            {...createOptions(this.props.fontSize)}
          />
        </label>
        <button>Pay</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
const CardForm = injectStripe(_CardForm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should trigger your call to the server once you get your token, i.e in the `then` clause of the promise that `this.props.stripe.createToken` returns.

```
handleSubmit = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  this.props.stripe.createToken()
    .then((payload) => yourFetchImplementation('path/to/api/endpoint', payloadAsBody));
}
```